# How can I create a custom view in XIB with different init method?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xib

I know how to layout and create a UIView in xib,
but now I have a custom view(subview of UIView),
it has different init methods like:

```
-(id)initWithArg1:(int) arg2:(NSString *) arg3:(NSArray *) ...
```

or

```
+(id)viewWithArg1:(int) arg2:(NSString *) arg3:(NSArray *) ...
```

When I set view's class to mine in xib property right bar,
my custom init method doesn't appear, nowhere to set.

so how? thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carl is correct.

In essence if an object is instantiated from a XIB (following the steps you mention in the question) then the initialiser which gets called is

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder;
```

You can confirm this for yourself by over-riding every possible initialiser and putting breakpoints in all of them to see which is called.

So, If you are initialising from the XIB it kind of hints that you will have one instance of that object (not necessarily so); however if you need lots of instances of a custom object then you might consider going back to a custom initialiser and forgo the XIB work by creating everything programatically.

In essence, Think how you are going to be using the object. This will tell you if you need to be thinking of custom initialisers that create their own view programatically.

Comment: yes,I think it works by confirm <NSCoding> and implement that method. All I need is to layout my views,I can just set other vars programatically.Further,can I set them visiable,like standard objects in UIKit,set a label's text,color or something?thanks.

Comment: glad to be of help. Mark up's & acceptance always go a long way too ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to override `initWithCoder:` and use some sensible default values to accomplish what the designated initializers are doing.

e.g.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        _value1 = 0;
        _value2 = @"Hi!";
        /* and so on */
    }

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not need to set `init` method in xib, in other place you just call the `init` by code like this:

```
[[yourView alloc] initWithArg1:arg1 Arg2:arg2];
```

Comment: Then how will he use his view in a nib?